# Number of combinations with restrictions in R

Tags: r, unique, combinations, sample

Dear R and stats community,

How many combinations are possible to select 3 objects from a total of 9 objects in a way that 3 selected objects do not repeat themselves in one external characteristic?

In my example, three selected specimens must always differ in their *species* attribute. That is, in the selection of 3, there should always be one representative of species A, one of species B and one of species C, and the order within this selection does not matter.

```
> mydata <- data.frame(specimens = paste("s", 1:9, sep = ""), species = LETTERS[1:3])
> mydata
  specimens species
1        s1       A
2        s2       B
3        s3       C
4        s4       A
5        s5       B
6        s6       C
7        s7       A
8        s8       B
9        s9       C
```

How many combinations are there?
I know how to count the combinations of ANY set of three objects with e.g. `arrangements::ncombinations(9,3)` or `choose(9,3)`.

I have seen that one way for generating combinations that allows pasting a custom function which could help in selecting combinations with required properties.

```
library(utils)
combn(mydata$specimens, 3, FUN)
```

I am not able to design such a function by myself. One of the unsuccessful trials is

```
library(utils)
outp <- combn(as.character(mydata$specimens), 3, function(x) !duplicated(mydata$species))
> outp[, 1:10]
       [,1]  [,2]  [,3]  [,4]  [,5]  [,6]  [,7]  [,8]  [,9] [,10]
 [1,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [2,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [3,]  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE  TRUE
 [4,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [5,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [6,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [7,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [8,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
 [9,] FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE FALSE
```

Thanks in advance for your help.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There has to be an A, a B and a C. There are 3 possible As. Each of these must appear with one of the Bs, so there are 3 * 3 = 9 possible pairs of As and Bs. Each of these pairs can be grouped with one of the 3 Cs, so there are 3 * 3 * 3 = 27 possible combinations.

You can see them all using this one-liner:

```r
expand.grid(split(mydata$specimens, mydata$species))
#>     A  B  C
#> 1  s1 s2 s3
#> 2  s4 s2 s3
#> 3  s7 s2 s3
#> 4  s1 s5 s3
#> 5  s4 s5 s3
#> 6  s7 s5 s3
#> 7  s1 s8 s3
#> 8  s4 s8 s3
#> 9  s7 s8 s3
#> 10 s1 s2 s6
#> 11 s4 s2 s6
#> 12 s7 s2 s6
#> 13 s1 s5 s6
#> 14 s4 s5 s6
#> 15 s7 s5 s6
#> 16 s1 s8 s6
#> 17 s4 s8 s6
#> 18 s7 s8 s6
#> 19 s1 s2 s9
#> 20 s4 s2 s9
#> 21 s7 s2 s9
#> 22 s1 s5 s9
#> 23 s4 s5 s9
#> 24 s7 s5 s9
#> 25 s1 s8 s9
#> 26 s4 s8 s9
#> 27 s7 s8 s9
```

Answer (score 3):

You can try `interaction` over `split` like below

```
> levels(interaction(with(mydata, split(specimens,species))))
 [1] "s1.s2.s3" "s4.s2.s3" "s7.s2.s3" "s1.s5.s3" "s4.s5.s3" "s7.s5.s3"
 [7] "s1.s8.s3" "s4.s8.s3" "s7.s8.s3" "s1.s2.s6" "s4.s2.s6" "s7.s2.s6"
[13] "s1.s5.s6" "s4.s5.s6" "s7.s5.s6" "s1.s8.s6" "s4.s8.s6" "s7.s8.s6"
[19] "s1.s2.s9" "s4.s2.s9" "s7.s2.s9" "s1.s5.s9" "s4.s5.s9" "s7.s5.s9"
[25] "s1.s8.s9" "s4.s8.s9" "s7.s8.s9"
```

which shows you all combinations of component `specimens` from different `species`